# ng test throws error on angular material components

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I'm getting multiple failures when I run `ng test` in my Angualr 8 project on angular material components.
I haven't written any specific test cases for these scenarios.

```
DeleteBotModalComponent > should create
Failed: Template parse errors:
'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("     <mat-form-field class="col-md-6 example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    [ERROR ->]<mat-label>Bot ID</mat-label>
                    <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="id"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DeleteBotModalComponent.html@8:20
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("m class="example-form" [formGroup]="botDeleteForm">
            <div class="row">
                [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field class="col-md-6 example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-l"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DeleteBotModalComponent.html@7:16
'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("     <mat-form-field class="col-md-6 example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    [ERROR ->]<mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                    <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="name"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DeleteBotModalComponent.html@12:20
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("id" placeholder="id" name="id" readonly="true">
                </mat-form-field>
                [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field class="col-md-6 example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-l"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/
```

Below is my delete-bot-modal.component.spec.ts file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DeleteBotModalComponent } from './delete-bot-modal.component';

describe('DeleteBotModalComponent', () => {
  let component: DeleteBotModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeleteBotModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DeleteBotModalComponent ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeleteBotModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Can someone tell me the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular component tests, if your component has dependencies, you need to either mock them or import them. With Material components, this means importing the modules for any components used in the tested component when configuring the testing module. For example:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DeleteBotModalComponent ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule, // any necessary modules
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Of course, you can also create a shared module which imports and exports all of these to make it quicker and easier to write tests.